# A consequence of Itô's lemma

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, stochastic-differential-equations

In its simplest form, for any twice continuously differentiable function $f$ on the reals and Itô process $X_t$, it states that $f(t, X_t)$ is itself an Itô process.
Every Itô process, for suitable conditions on drift and diffusion functions (see p.88 of "Stochastic Differential Equations and Applications" 2nd Edition, by X. Mao) is a Markov process.
**Does that mean $f(t, X_t)$ is Markov without further requirements on $f$?**
I read in another post that $f$ should be injective for this to be true, so twice differentiability doesn't seem enough.
But then Itô's lemma wouldn't hold. I don't know

Comment: $Y_t=f(t,X_t)$ is a Markov process with respect to the filtration $\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma(X_s:s\leq t)$. It may fail to be a Markov process with respect to the filtration $\mathcal{F}'_t=\sigma(Y_s:s\leq t)$ if $f$ is not injective.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't picture what it means to be Markov with respect to some filtration or another. Would you mind explaining it in words (at the price to simplifying things)?

Comment: I would be surprised if the textbook or whatever material about Markov process you are reading does not mention the notion of filtration. But in short, a filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\in T}$, parametrized via a time interval $T$, is an increasing family of $\sigma$-algebras that models our accumulated knowledge/information about the process up to a given time. Then the natural filtration $\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma(X_s:s\leq t)$ basically models all the information we can know about the process $X$ up to time $t$ (but not beyond that point).